# IE 11 Stripping out Tags (Alt & Aria)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, tags, alt

Using IE 11 I'm running into a bug that strips out tags in the DOM when viewing through the inspector (possibly only in the inspector). I've hit this issue with alt tags as well as various Aria tags but I don't think there's a pattern. Here is an example from google. Any thoughts?
[image]